# How to prevent pixelation/blurryness on CSS3 scale

Tags: css

I have a CSS rule that makes an image scale on hover by 1.5x. Is there a browser hack or anything that can be done to prevent the image from looking pixelated / blurred?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to magically add more detail to the image.

Comment: The "CSI Miami: Zoom Enhance" feature isn't available for public use, yet!

Comment: Is your image a photograph? Or a logo? You might be able to use some HTML5 / SVG drawing libraries to reproduce the logo if it's fairly simple flat shapes. THEN you just might be able to zoom it at 1.5x, 2.0x, 1000.0x! (Discourage the use of 1000.0x though, might aggravate a few users.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a 100x100 image and scale it up to 150x150, of course it's going to look blurry. What I would do is start out with a 150x150 image, and scale it *down* to 100x100 - then on hover, resize it back to 150x150. If that still doesn't look good, then you should make two image files, one large and one small, and swap them out.

Comment: Duh! Don't know why I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 0):

There's pretty much nothing you can do that will help an image to scale *up*. Browsers are very good at scaling images *down* efficiently, and you shouldn't need to apply any special CSS attributes to get your images to scale down properly. But increasing the size/resolution of an image is something that neither browsers nor CSS can help you with.